# Interpretation of Loss and validation Loss in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, tensorflow, loss-function

I am building a model to predict one label by taking one feature as an input. The two variables seems to be strongly correlated. I wanted to build a (sequential) Neural Network model with Keras in python. However I don't have much experience in this topic.
For 20 epochs, this was the output:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
history= model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.15, validation_data=None, verbose=1  )

Epoch 1/20
556/563 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 34669264.0000 - mse: 34669264.0000WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_test_batch_begin` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0000s vs `on_test_batch_begin` time: 0.0010s). Check your callbacks.
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 34285784.0000 - mse: 34285784.0000 - val_loss: 96.6166 - val_mse: 96.6166
Epoch 2/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 99.0922 - mse: 99.0922 - val_loss: 97.5675 - val_mse: 97.5675
Epoch 3/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 99.9443 - mse: 99.9443 - val_loss: 99.2140 - val_mse: 99.2140
Epoch 4/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 102.9865 - mse: 102.9865 - val_loss: 118.3417 - val_mse: 118.3417
Epoch 5/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 106.5720 - mse: 106.5720 - val_loss: 97.8411 - val_mse: 97.8411
Epoch 6/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 947us/step - loss: 105.5193 - mse: 105.5193 - val_loss: 102.9201 - val_mse: 102.9201
Epoch 7/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 956us/step - loss: 111.6952 - mse: 111.6952 - val_loss: 152.1037 - val_mse: 152.1037
Epoch 8/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 956us/step - loss: 108.9572 - mse: 108.9572 - val_loss: 97.3432 - val_mse: 97.3432
Epoch 9/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 116.4152 - mse: 116.4152 - val_loss: 281.0902 - val_mse: 281.0902
Epoch 10/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 152.9690 - mse: 152.9690 - val_loss: 489.1042 - val_mse: 489.1042
Epoch 11/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 190.2841 - mse: 190.2841 - val_loss: 117.8673 - val_mse: 117.8673
Epoch 12/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 337.4025 - mse: 337.4025 - val_loss: 1454.0408 - val_mse: 1454.0408
Epoch 13/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 5692.8813 - mse: 5692.8813 - val_loss: 4738.1577 - val_mse: 4738.1577
Epoch 14/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 8999.7559 - mse: 8999.7559 - val_loss: 1928.1060 - val_mse: 1928.1060
Epoch 15/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 8781.1357 - mse: 8781.1357 - val_loss: 100.8937 - val_mse: 100.8937
Epoch 16/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 9043.8174 - mse: 9043.8174 - val_loss: 734.2968 - val_mse: 734.2968
Epoch 17/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 8870.1094 - mse: 8870.1094 - val_loss: 604.0785 - val_mse: 604.0785
Epoch 18/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 7896.2520 - mse: 7896.2520 - val_loss: 9735.1504 - val_mse: 9735.1504
Epoch 19/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 37979.0586 - mse: 37979.0586 - val_loss: 315.8015 - val_mse: 315.8015
Epoch 20/20
563/563 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 282.4867 - mse: 282.4867 - val_loss: 350.4554 - val_mse: 350.4554
```

And these are the plots for the loss (in Blue) and validation loss (in Red):

[image]
[image]

The loss function (mse) is minimized after two epochs which I guess means that the model 'learned' at the point. I don't understand however why the validation loss has huge fluctuations. I thought that it would have a similar distribution to the loss function.

Can anyone please help me interpret these two plots?

**UPDATE**: AFTER SCALING THE INPUT VARIABLES & CHOOSING A SMALER LEARNING RATE
[image]

Comment: So just a logistic regression problem?  I would formulate it that way (you need to use a cross entropy for class labels and not a MSE) and I also suspect you have not normalized your input data.  I would also try lowering your learning rate.

Comment: @neuroguy123, it's a linear regression problem, my variables are continuous. That's why I chose MSE. I scaled my input data using Sklearn.StandardScaler() and I put the learning rate=0.01, I will update my question with the newer plot of the loss and validation loss function plot. Could you give me your opinion about that? The loss function in blue looks more realistic now but there are still some fluctuations in the validation function.

Comment: Try regularization, variance of the model may be high. Add dropout layers to model, try l2 loss.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely getting there, but it's a bumpy learning.  You could lower the rate again and regularize as suggested.  You could also play with the capacity of your network.  It could be too complex for the problem.

Comment: Seems you have scaled Y too. Keep Y unscaled.